# Unpivot pairs in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I have a table with following data structure and data .

```
declare @temp table 
 ( 

  Name nvarchar(500),
  Class1 decimal(18,2), 
  Class1P decimal(18,2),  
  Class1S decimal(18,2),
   Class2 decimal(18,2), 
  Class2P decimal(18,2),  
  Class2S decimal(18,2),
   Class3 decimal(18,2), 
  Class3P decimal(18,2),  
  Class3S decimal(18,2)
  )

INSERT INTO @temp 
  SELECT 'Rahul',101,102,103,201,202,203,301,302,303
```

Now currently its show me data in such form for a simple select statement.

[image: simple select statement result]

but i want to show the data in such format . I have idea that i have to first unpivot data then need to pivot the data but facing issue with syntax of unpiovt and pivot.

[image: expected result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify what version of SQL Server you are using but since you need to unpivot pairs of columns, you can use [`CROSS APPLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

```
select 
  t.Name,
  c.Class, 
  c.Class1P, 
  c.Class1S
from @temp t
cross apply
(
  values
    (Class1, Class1P, Class1S),
    (Class2, Class2P, Class3S),
    (Class3, Class3P, Class3S)
) c (Class, Class1P, Class1S);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/35482/0).  The above uses the `VALUES` which was made available in SQL Server 2008, if you are using SQL Server 2005, then you can replace `VALUES` with `SELECT...UNION ALL`.

Comment: Great example. This is an alternative to unpivot with a lot more control.

Answer (score 1):

No need to pivot. just union 3 seperate queries together...

```
declare @temp table 
 ( 

  Name nvarchar(500),
  Class1 decimal(18,2), 
  Class1P decimal(18,2),  
  Class1S decimal(18,2),
  Class2 decimal(18,2), 
  Class2P decimal(18,2),  
  Class2S decimal(18,2),
  Class3 decimal(18,2), 
  Class3P decimal(18,2),  
  Class3S decimal(18,2)
  )

INSERT INTO @temp 
  SELECT 'Rahul',101,102,103,201,202,203,301,302,303
INSERT INTO @temp 
  SELECT 'Eoin',701,702,703,801,802,803,901,902,903

SELECT Name, Class1 as Class, Class1P as ClassP, Class1S as ClassS FROM @temp
UNION
SELECT Name, Class2, Class2P, Class2S FROM @temp
UNION
SELECT Name, Class3, Class3P, Class3S FROM @temp
```

RETURNS the results.

```
Name                 Class                                   ClassP                                  ClassS
-------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
Eoin                 701.00                                  702.00                                  703.00
Eoin                 801.00                                  802.00                                  803.00
Eoin                 901.00                                  902.00                                  903.00
Rahul                101.00                                  102.00                                  103.00
Rahul                201.00                                  202.00                                  203.00
Rahul                301.00                                  302.00                                  303.00
```